# Need to read consecutive spaces as a word in c++

Tags: c++, string, loops, file-io

I need to read words from a file and store them in an array of string objects. But, the problem is I need to consider multiple spaces as a word.
For example,

```
I   am.
```

This is just two words that have three three spaces between them. But, I need to show this:

```
arr[0]="I"
arr[1]=" "
arr[2]=" "
arr[3]="am"
```

Can anyone please help me out? This is the code that I wrote:

```
strSet = new std::string[noStrings];
file.open(filename);
if (file) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (file>>strSet[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at it one character at a time?

Comment: How do three spaces become two single-space strings? What should happen to a single space between two non-whitespace words? If you can explain the logic clearly, you can probably program it.

Comment: *"This is the code that I wrote:"* -- that's a starting point. Why is it not a finishing point?

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, `file >> string` would indeed read word by word ignoring any whitespace character.

The simplest way, that I know of, to record spaces would be through reading an entire line and later parsing the line.
Here's my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> readWords(std::ifstream& file, size_t reservedSize = 0) {
        std::string buffer;
        std::vector<std::string> words;
        words.reserve(reservedSize);

        //while there is still something to read
        while (file.good()) {
                //read a line
                std::getline(file, buffer);
                for(size_t start = 0, end = 0; start < buffer.length();) {
                        //if a space is encountered
                        if (buffer[start] == ' ') {
                                //ignore the first space
                                ++start;
                                end = start;
                                //count how many consecutive spaces
                                while(end < buffer.length() && buffer[end] == ' ')
                                        ++end;
                                //save spaces as separete strings
                                for (; start != end; ++start)
                                        words.emplace_back(" ");
                        }
                        else {
                                //skip all whitespace characters, except ' '
                                while(start < buffer.length() &&
                                        buffer[start] == '\v' &&
                                        buffer[start] == '\r' &&
                                        buffer[start] == '\n')
                                        ++start;
                                //count how many consecutive non whitespace characters
                                while(end < buffer.length() && !isspace(buffer[end])) ++end;
                                //add to array
                                words.push_back(buffer.substr(start, end - start));
                                //don't forget to increment start to avoid
                                //infinite loops
                                start += end - start;
                        }
                }
        }
        //return the array
        return words;
}



int main() {
        std::ifstream stream("input.txt");
        auto words = readWords(stream);
        for (const auto& e : words) {
                std::cout << '\'' << e << "'\n";
        }
}
```

file input.txt ('\'s are not in the file, they show where lines end):

```
I   am.\
  hello fellow  friend    \
```

Output:

```
'I'
' '
' '
'am.'
' '
'hello'
'fellow'
' '
'friend'
' '
' '
' '
```